# CSS - Header/footer background relative to content

Tags: css, background, header, footer

I'm trying to make the layout of a website which has separate backgrounds for the header and footer. So this is basically how I do:

```
body{
    background: url(images/header.png) top center no-repeat,
            url(images/footer2.png) bottom center no-repeat,
                url(images/bg.jpg) fixed;
    background-size: contain, contain, auto;
}
```

The reason why I choose to do this is because when I apply the backgrounds for the header and footer (instead of the body), the background can not cover the width of the screen. But there's this bug: when I zoom in or zoom out, only the size of the content changes, while the sizes of the backgrounds remain the same like in the screenshot below:
[image]

What could be the best solution in this case? I'm looking for a pure CSS solution (not having to alter the HTML markup). Please help me out and thanks.

Comment: *"not having to alter the HTML markup"*. What is your HTML markup? Please show the relevant parts.

Comment: Actually it's kinda irrelevant, I'm required to style a predefined html with CSS only so I hope that I don't have to add any additional div. I just basically have two divs: one for the header and one for the footer. But that's not the main point here right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `contain` in your background definition. This keeps the size of the image as big as the body, and the body is staying at full size.

Try using repeat-x instead of no-repeat, and set width part of the background-size to the same value as the width the header element has.

That should make it scale to match, unless I'm missing something.